# How to parse Django templates for template tags

Tags: python, django

### Situation

I'm writing a checker program that checks Django templates. For example I want to check if all Django templates that use `url` template tag, use it with quotes on first parameter so that it is Django 1.5 compatible. Also I want to check that they have included `{% load url from future %}` in their templates.

For example if my program parses the following Django template, I want it to raise an exception.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<td>
  <a href="{% url first second %}">
  </a>
</td>
```

But this template should get parsed without exception.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load url from future %}
<td>
  <a href="{% url 'first' second %}">
  </a>
</td>
```

I'm not limited to this simple example. I have other parsings to do. For example I want to check how many `load` template tags are present in the template.

### Question

How can I elegantly solve this parsing problem?

- I don't want to use regular expressions.
- I this Django it self has some utilities in this regard. I think using them is a good idea, but I don't know how.
- I want to run the program separately from Django. So I don't want Django to run the program itself (with `render_to_response`). (**This is important**)

### Code

Please show me some code that can solve the example I mentioned. I want to detect whether `{% load url from future %}` is in the code. Also I want to check every `url` template tag and check if the first argument is quoted.

**Bonus**:

- I want to be able to see the rendered HTML that Django generates from this template, and do my HTML parsing on it. (for example with PyQuery)

Comment: I can't answer your main question however to get django to parse templates but not have it return a http response you can use render_to_string which will spit out the compiled HTML: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

Comment: According to the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html), "most of the parsing happens via a call to a single regular expression". So you might be better off by simply finding and importing or copying that RegEx from the Django source code than to build a real parser.

Comment: Also, why don't you want to use a regex?

Comment: @limelights the main reason is, the result of that might become a huge spaghetti code.

Comment: use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.get_template to parse the template and compile it in the django shell, then poke around at the object using dir() until you find the info you want.

Comment: Can't you use Django 1.5 instead of future-proofing your app?

Comment: [There](https://github.com/futurecolors/django-future-url) is an attempt of doing your task with regular expressions. May be it'll help you

Comment: @Secator I'm not writing a Django app. I want to write an app that does some processing on a bunch of Django apps. I can't update any of them to 1.5

Comment: Use a single regex that matches template tags. That should be pretty easy and clean. Then you might want to use a proper parser to parse each tag into its components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the `compile_string` method.

```
 >>> from django.template.base import *
 >>> settings.configure()
 >>> compile_string("<a href='ab'></a>{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' as rowcolors %}", None)
 >>> [<Text Node: '<a href='ab'></a>'>, <django.template.defaulttags.CycleNode object at 0x10511b210>]
```

The compile string method is utilized by the `Template` class and is the method used to produce the node list.
Tested in Django 1.8 Alpha.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1f8bb95cc2286a882e0f7a4692f77b285d811d11/django/template/base.py

Answer (score 9):

You say...

> I want to check if all Django templates that use url
>   template tag, use it with quotes on first parameter so that it is
>   Django 1.5 compatible.

...and...

> I don't want to use regular expressions.

...because...

> the result of that might become a huge spaghetti code

...but, frankly, writing a parser from scratch is likely to be even messier than using a regular expression. I don't see what's so messy about a regex as simple as something like...

```
"{% *url +[^']"
```

...and I doubt there's a non-regex-based solution that's as terse as that.

With regards to...

> Also I want to check that they have included
>   `{% load url from future %}` in their templates.

If your intention is to ensure Django 1.5 compatibility, this is pointless. According to the [Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/), the new-style url tag syntax is enabled by default, so the line `{% load url from future %}` won't have any effect.

And in versions prior to 1.5, it's much simpler just to put...

```
import django.template
django.template.add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.future')
```

...at the bottom of your `settings.py` and be done with it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Next code still uses django, but it can check if syntax is correct:

```
>>> from django.template import Template
>>> from django.template.defaulttags import URLNode
>>> t = Template("{% load url from future %}\n{% url projects_list company.slug %}")
>>> for node in t.nodelist:
...     if isinstance(node, URLNode):
...         for arg in node.args: print(arg)
... 
company.slug
>>> t2 = Template('{% load url from future %}\n{% url "projects_list" company.slug }')
>>> for node in t2.nodelist:
...     print(node)
... 
<django.template.defaulttags.LoadNode object at 0x32145d0>
<Text Node: '
{% url "projects_list" c'>
>>>
```

As you see last node is not URLNode

Comment: I think that the last line of code you have written has syntax error: `t2 = Template("{% load url from future %}\n ...` The syntax error in because you have use double quotations, if you use single quotations it will work.

Comment: Thanks. Replaced that line with another example